# Selecting class inside element:first-child

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a simple pie, a circle divided in four pieces:

```
<ul class='pie'>
    <li class='slice'>
        <div class='slice-contents'></div>
    </li>
    <li class='slice'>
        <div class='slice-contents'></div>
    </li>
    <li class='slice'>
        <div class='slice-contents'></div>
    </li>
    <li class='slice'>
        <div class='slice-contents'></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have this CSS:

```
.pie {
        position: relative;
        margin: 1em auto;
        border: dashed 1px;
        padding: 0;
        width: 32em;
        height: 32em;
        border-radius: 50%;
        list-style: none;
    }
    .slice {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0; right: 0;
        width: 50%; height: 50%;
        transform-origin: 0% 100%;
    }
    .slice-contents {
        position: absolute;
        left: -100%;
        width: 200%; height: 200%;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
    .slice:first-child {
        transform: rotate(15deg) skewY(-90deg);
    }
    .slice:first-child .slice-contents { background-color: lightblue; }
    .slice:hover .slice-contents { background-color: violet; }
```

`.slice:first-child .slice-contents` doesn't select anything but `.slice:hover .slice-contents` does.

Why is this?

Comment: The selector is working fine … it’s the whole element that is not visible, because of the transform you applied to it. Remove the transform, and you will immediately see it showing up, in lightblue. After that, go figure out what the _correct_ transformation would be to show the element wherever you want it to …

Comment: OMG you're right! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The selector is working fine.

It’s the whole element that is not visible, because of the transform you applied to it. Remove the transform, and you will immediately see it showing up, in lightblue.

---

(So now you’ll need to go and figure out what the correct transformation would be to show the element wherever you want it to …)